# Proving that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal{S}_n$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, permutations

**Question.** Suppose $n>2$. Let $$H:=\{f\in\mathcal{S}_n: f\cdot 1=1\ \text{and}\ f\cdot2=2\}.$$ Is $H$ a subgroup of $\mathcal{S}_n$?

**Attempt.** $H$ describes all the permutations that leave $1$ and $2$ fixed. The order of this group is $(n-2)!$. Since this is a divisor of the order of $\mathcal{S}_n$; by Lagrange, we conclude that $H$ is a subgroup.

Satisfied with this reasoning?

Comment: You need to revise your understanding of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Who voted to close as off topic? It has a clear attempt!

Comment: @Shaun I don't think mocking people is productive :) Let's help each other learn

Comment: @William I think you misunderstood my comment. I think this is a high quality question.

Comment: @Shaun re-read, apologies.

Comment: Hint: Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this is my best shot.

The solution, I believe, is simple. Consider $a, b \in H$. Since both fix 1 and 2, then $ab$ fixes 1 and 2. (Closure.) Since $a$ fixes 1 and 2, $a^{-1}$ must fix 1 and 2, as well. (Inverses.) The identity fixes 1 and 2. (Identity.) That proves it's a subgroup.

Your reasoning, while more sophisticated, mistakenly reverses the statement made by Lagrange's theorem. Lagrange states that a subgroup's order must divide the order of the group. It doesn't say that there exists a subgroup of each divisor of the group's order.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the error of my ways now. Thank you very much for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @thesmallprint glad to help. I imagine you're doing this for a course and as someone who has been out of school a while, man do I miss what you're doing right now :) enjoy.